# I am trying to plot a simple graph on X on Y. However the X values do not start at Y intercept even though in the data values start from 0

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to graph x = time and y = weight grouped by subject/code (n = 20).

Here is the structure of the data

```
time                      : int  0 6 12 0 6 12 0 6 12 0 ...
weight                    : num  84.1 80.6 77.8 87.2 83.6 ...
code                      : int  100 100 100 102 102 102 105 105 105 108 ...
```

Weight of subjects was recorded at three different times 0,6,12. I would like to graph a simple graph on ggplot where baseline weight starts its intercept at Y. However, for some reason there is a gap between Y axis and baseline values of weight at time = 0.

```
library(ggplot2)
ancestral$code <- factor(ancestral$code)
colnames(ancestral)[1] <- "subject"
p <- ggplot(data = ancestral, aes(x = time, y = weight, group = subject, colour = subject))
p + geom_point()
p + geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE)

ancestral <- 
   structure(list(subject = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("100", "102", "105", "108", "109", 
"121", "123", "131", "141", "144", "151", "152", "160", "170", 
"171", "173", "174", "178", "179", "180"), class = "factor"), 
treatment = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a"), age = c(43L, 43L, 43L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 
40L), sex = c("f", "f", "f", "m", "m", "m", "f", "f", "f", 
"f"), dietary.recall = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L), kcal = c(1797.720986, 1751.17536, 2855.074446, 1949.61977, 
1141.0354, 1620.56448, 600.669632, 740.00679, 549.0784, 2566.250775
), prot = c(71.736202, 91.410806, 136.916646, 103.662363, 
51.323997, 84.436275, 50.986962, 58.6691, 61.463962, 152.871809
), tfat = c(95.235229, 104.097796, 185.577553, 93.246043, 
61.475655, 78.86543, 29.682694, 33.214566, 30.89685, 130.999495
), carb = c(180.091481, 127.22832, 193.141345, 190.854277, 
102.39441, 150.7403, 36.082023, 61.358365, 3.695049, 205.240558
), mois = c(3672.506752, 3075.785473, 2899.597451, 3418.412722, 
2310.71662, 2352.163899, 5447.33199, 3630.148673, 2464.842693, 
2548.682003), sfat = c(28.824053, 24.894926, 73.622008, 22.515582, 
15.564264, 19.029535, 6.346358, 5.276456, 9.473475, 31.663894
), mfat = c(38.056705, 54.736549, 67.874898, 34.685475, 25.623133, 
35.388061, 15.92461, 16.474252, 12.67658, 64.132485), pfat =    c(19.306687, 
16.184698, 29.008312, 25.400063, 15.832114, 19.052413, 4.151889, 
7.811625, 4.465024, 25.066706), vegetabletotal = c(3.00073, 
0.77311, 1.3349, 3.913937, 0.7207, 1.00016, 1.895042, 7.264672, 
0.561145, 8.404792), meatpoultryfishtotal = c(5.080814, 6.00586, 
6.279946, 5.0995, 3.976473, 5.928552, 6.221628, 5.476455, 
6.78093, 11.273118), fruittotal = c(4.063535, 2.942105, 2.905777, 
3.68358, 1.9208, 3.11433, 0.413848, 1.84902, 0.060864, 1.6421
), grainstotal = c(0.932148, 0.539105, 0, 1.754425, 0.833362, 
5.290366, 0, 0, 0, 3.159225), grainswhole = c(0, 0, 0, 1.00035, 
0.12558, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), grainsnonwhole = c(0.932148, 0.539105, 
0, 0.754075, 0.707852, 5.290366, 0, 0, 0, 3.159225), eggtotal = c(2.127754, 
1.96786, 3.69964, 1.96786, 1.192096, 0.242676, 1.00012, 1.00004, 
1.00004, 0.88), nutsandseedstotal = c(0, 1.01592, 5.386492, 
3.439312, 2.275238, 2.257599, 1, 1, 0, 5.00905), legumestotal = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fishhiomega = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fishlowomega = c(0, 0, 5.555466, 0, 3.05046, 
5.928552, 2.22201, 3.09573, 0, 0), dairytotal = c(0.65371, 
1.522625, 2.24531, 1.486084, 0.209538, 1.180116, 0, 0, 0, 
1.792215), addedsugartotal = c(5.847966, 5.316699, 13.85028, 
8.42709, 3.223059, 0.324324, 0, 0.00015, 0, 5.07767), oiltotal = c(24.014096, 
8.815969, 27.608399, 40.250553, 28.198416, 30.566465, 6.85568, 
10.50872, 2.25308, 55.641045), solidfatstotal = c(19.747537, 
23.913016, 74.731634, 21.328068, 18.60801, 34.629744, 2.3232, 
2.32208, 8.2172, 35.292557), vegetabletotallog = c(1.386476844, 
0.572735067, 0.847969064, 1.592075454, 0.542731185, 0.693227177, 
1.062999619, 2.111990045, 0.445419526, 2.241219347),    meatpoultryfishtotaltuk1.5 = c(1.844764256, 
1.925329873, 1.947903282, 1.846465025, 1.737852084, 1.918862495, 
1.943145783, 1.880101557, 1.987813849, 2.288476728), fruittotaldi =    c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), grainstotaldi = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L), grainswholedi = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), grainsnonwholedi = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L), eggtotaldi = c(3L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), nutsandseedstotaldi = c(0L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L), legumestotaldi = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), fishhiomegadi = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), fishlowomegadi = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), dairytotaldi = c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L), addedsugartotaldi = c(2L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L), oiltotalsqrt = c(4.900417941, 
2.969169749, 5.254369515, 6.344332353, 5.310218075, 5.528694692, 
2.618335349, 3.241715595, 1.501026316, 7.459292527), solidfatstotallog = c(3.032427541, 
3.215390398, 4.32719596, 3.105844542, 2.975938156, 3.573180795, 
1.200928174, 1.200591093, 2.221071304, 3.591612679), time = c(0L, 
6L, 12L, 0L, 6L, 12L, 0L, 6L, 12L, 0L), bicep = c(14.16, 
15, 11.34, 10.16, 9.34, 17, 22, 19, 15, 9), tricep = c(31, 
25.67, 28, 21.83, 18, 20, 29.34, 30, 26.34, 20), subscapular = c(25, 
25, 25.34, 19, 16.34, 15, 20, 25.34, 23.34, 8), suprailiac = c(26.34, 
29.34, 24.67, 28.84, 33.34, 29.67, 30.67, 30.34, 26.67, 18.67
), weight = c(84.1, 80.6, 77.8, 87.18, 83.64, 80.01, 100.3, 
91.45, 86, 63.95), wc = c(95.5, 93, 95, 93, 92, 90, 114, 
110, 99.34, 74), bia = c(41.1, 40.8, 38.9, 22.4, 23.3, 21.8, 
44.9, 43, 40.1, 28.8), height = c(167, 167, 167, 167.6, 167.6, 
167.6, 167.6, 167.6, 167.6, 177.8), bmi = c(30.15525835, 
28.90028327, 27.8963032, 31.03622103, 29.7759753, 28.48368943, 
35.70696225, 32.55634794, 30.61613912, 20.22912209), wthr = c(0.571856287, 
0.556886228, 0.568862275, 0.554892601, 0.548926014, 0.53699284, 
0.680190931, 0.656324582, 0.592720764, 0.416197975), density = c(1.015224033, 
1.015710609, 1.017631192, 1.040783101, 1.041766658, 1.040157646, 
1.013487722, 1.012679813, 1.016938984, 1.032425272), X.fat = c(37.57710978, 
37.34353621, 36.42376918, 25.60341795, 25.15438918, 25.88940164, 
38.41242885, 38.80208121, 36.75486696, 29.453587), fm = c(31.60234932, 
30.09889018, 28.33769242, 22.32105977, 21.03913111, 20.71411025, 
38.52766614, 35.48450327, 31.60918559, 18.83556889), ffm = c(52.49765068, 
50.50110982, 49.46230758, 64.85894023, 62.60086889, 59.29588975, 
61.77233386, 55.96549673, 54.39081441, 45.11443111), time1 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "6", 
"12"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Edit1

```
ancestral$code <- factor(ancestral$code)
colnames(ancestral)[1] <- "subject"
ggplot(data = ancestral, aes(x = time, y = weight, group = subject,   colour = subject)) +
geom_point() + 
geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE) +  
scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = c(0, 6, 12))
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/843Z3.png

Comment: a `dput(ancestral)` would help see what is going on.

Comment: It is a very large data frame. Is there way to limit frame to show relevant data?

Comment: You can do `dput(head(ancestral, 30))`

Comment: Thanks, It was still very large I did dput(head(ancestral, 10))

Comment: Do you mean the gap between zero and the y-axis?https://imgur.com/a/W8xxSzE

Comment: Yes! Also I only want 0,6,12 x-axis labels for time.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/YFTj7VC.png please see this. I see data points (solid colored circles) at time 0,6,12 apart from the lines themselves. I am using the same code and data as you.

Comment: Because you are drawing a linear line between the two points, not connecting the two points. Use `geom_line()` instead if you want to connect the points.

Comment: I see, is there way to retain the regression line and delete the data points?

Comment: just remove `geom_point()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `scale_x_continuous()` to set `expand` and `breaks`

```
ggplot(data = ancestral, aes(x = time, y = weight, group = subject, colour = subject)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE) +  
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = c(0, 6, 12))
```

[image]

edit: Connecting points using `geom_line()`

```
ggplot(data = ancestral, aes(x = time, y = weight, group = subject, colour = subject)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = c(0, 6, 12))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I just did that but now I see data points at three different times.I will upload a imgur of it. and update my original post to show what I typed.